# What are some of the common techniques for density estimation?

Tags: probability, statistics, machine-learning, parameter-estimation

I'm trying to estimate the probability density function of a real random variable given its iid realizations. What are some of the standard techniques to do this? Also, is there any reasonable assumptions on the smoothness of the probability density function that's being commonly used in this field?

I'd greatly appreciate any of your pointers or references.

Comment: This question might get better answers at stats (dot) stackexchange (dot) com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Traditionally, histograms have been used as density estimators. Various
algorithms for the number of bins, based on the number of observations,
are in use. Rationales for these algorithms are based on the goal that
the histogram should give an idea of the shape of the population distribution.
Section 3.2 of the [Wikipedia article on histograms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) shows several commonly implemented
rules.

However, in binning the data to make a histogram, some information is lost. 
Accordingly, an empirical CDF curve (jumping by $\frac{1}{n}$th at each observation)
is often a clearer indication of the population CDF than a histogram is of
the population PDF (density).  The plots below illustrate this for
a sample of size $n = 100$ from $\mathsf{Gamma}(shape=5,rate=1/10).$

[image]

```
set.seed(1776);  x = rgamma(100, 5, .1)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
  hist(x, prob=T, col="skyblue2", main="Histogram: Sample of 100 from GAMMA(5,rate=.1)")
    curve(dgamma(x,5, .1), col="blue", lwd=3, add=T)
  plot(ecdf(x), main="ECDF: Sample of 100 from Gamma(4, rate=.1)"); 
    curve(pgamma(x, 5,.1), lwd=3, col="blue", add=T)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

One modern method of density estimation, usually implemented by computer,
in a *kernel density estimator* (KDE). Roughly, curves are generated to approximate
the population density in various subintervals of the span of the data, and
then the the curves are fit together to form a smooth curve. The term 'kernel'
refers to the type of curve (perhaps part of a normal density curve), and
the term 'bandwidth' refers to the length of the subintervals. You can
see the [*relevant Wikipedia article*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) for a more technical explantation; I have found the book by Silverman (1985), referenced there to be
a very clearly written starting place.

KDEs are implemented in R statistical software. The figure below shows the
density curve (cyan) of $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=100, \sigma=15),$ a histogram of a random
sample of size $n=500$ from this distribution, and the default KDE (red) from R based
on the sample. (The tick marks below the horizontal axis show exact locations
of the 500 observations.)

[image]

```
set.seed(1234); m = 500;  mu = 100; sg = 15
x = rnorm(m, mu, sg)
hist(x, prob=T, col="skyblue3", main="Sample of 500 from NORM(100,15)")
curve(dnorm(x, mu, sg), lwd = 2, col="cyan", add=T)
lines(density(x), lwd=3, col="red")  # density estimator implemented here
```

*Note:* Of course, if you *know* the population is normal, then it is better to use this information and
to estimate $\mu$ by $\bar X = 100.04$ and $\sigma$ by $S = 15.5.$ Then
plot a normal density curve using these estimates.

```
mean(x);  sd(x)
## 100.0276
## 15.52221
```

Comment: nice charts look great. (+1)

Answer (score 3):

The most common methods are [Histograms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) and [Kernel Density Estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation).  Good references are "All of Nonparameteric Statistics" by Wasserman and "Density Estimation for Statistics and Data Analysis" by Silverman.

Yes, various smoothness assumptions play a role when you want to prove convergence of the estimate to the true density - see the suggested references for more info.