# Is a probability density funcion a function that represents a density histogram?

Tags: probability, statistics, density-function

Where " density " , plotted on the y-axis is defined as the value derived by deviding the frequency of a class by the total number of data by the class interval?

Comment: Perhaps also see [_this Q&A_](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2335353/what-are-some-of-the-common-techniques-for-density-estimation/2335378#2335378) on density estimation.

Answer (score 1):

A probability density function $f_X$ is not a histogram. What it says is $P(X \in [a,b])=\int_a^b f_X(x) dx$. Nothing more, nothing less.

However, one can convert a histogram into a probability density function, by choosing your units so that the total area under the histogram is $1$ and the area under each bar of the histogram is proportional to the number of samples appearing in the corresponding range. Then you can have a piecewise constant function (given by the height along the histogram) which will now be a probability density function. This can be useful for things like approximating a distribution from a sample, especially if you know the true distribution should be continuous.

But most probability density functions that we see in practice do not arise in this way, at least not directly.

Comment: Minor point, but usually it would be $X \in (a,b]$ in order to make the distribution right continuous. Not an issue here, of course.